# saving image from a webpage + saving its name too using PHP

Tags: php

how can i save an image from a web page , for example:

```
http://othersdomain.com/image/colorful.jpg
```

How can i save the image and save it to my directory "image" inside FTP.
and also get the "colorful" name from the link.

As a conclusion , it will get colorful.jpg and save in my directory with the same name and type then echo out the link to it(on my web server).

after being saved to my server , it will echo out somehting like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/image/colorful.jpg
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you search on Google how to download a file using PHP, how to extract a filename from a URL, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a file from another server using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://othersdomain.com/image/colorful.jpg');
```

Comment: ... and [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save it.

Comment: ... and [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the file name.